# Is it possible to get a prescription in the United States while abroad using an online medical service?

Tags: usa, health, drugs

I'm going to travel to the U.S as a tourist and I take a prescription medication that cannot be stopped, due to the complications and risk of not being allowed to get the medication into the country, I wanted to explore the option of getting a prescription inside the U.S

Could it be possible to do so before entering the U.S?

[edit]

I plan to visit for 3 months

The medications aren't in the list of controlled substances

I consider bringing medications a risk because the approval happens in the moment I'm entering the country, since it is a very important medication, I would prefer, if possible, to make sure I will have medication for the visit beforehand.
And alo because there's always the chance to commit a mistake, which if gets noted already far away from home it could be fatal.

Comment: How long are you planning to be in the US? Why do you think there’s a risk of not being able to get your prescription drug into the country? http://www.fda.gov/consumers/consumer-updates/5-tips-traveling-us-medications Is the drug on the controlled substance list? https://www.deadiversion.usdoj.gov/schedules/orangebook/c_cs_alpha.pdf

Comment: I'd ask your doctor for recommendation,

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. a) Do you want to bring 3 months worth of the drug with you when you enter the US? b) After you've entered the US, do you want to refill the prescription at a US pharmacy while you're in the US? c) After you've entered the US, do you want to have the prescription medicine shipped to you from outside the US?